# Serialize Bitmap Image as XML Console Application

Tags: c#, serialization, console-application

I am making a console application to serialize an image as xml. However all the examples I looked at haven't worked for me as I'm getting the same error all the time `"Bitmap does not contain a definition for 'Save'"`. I'm unsure why I don't have access to the save property as in the majority of examples Bitmap has this property.

[image]

[image]

My code is as follows

```
        Bitmap corolla = new Bitmap (@"C:\corolla.jpg", true); // some image file.

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        corolla.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

        xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(ms.GetBuffer().GetType());

        ser.Serialize(xw, ms.GetBuffer());

        Console.WriteLine("Serialized Content::");

        string sSerializedContent = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(sSerializedContent);

        xw.Close();
```

Comment: It's a compile time error

Comment: I have added a screenshot

Comment: What happens when you click 'Show potential fixes'?

Comment: I have added a new image to show the potential fixs

Comment: Normally, you should create a class with a public default constructor and a 'byte[]' property for the bitmap buffer. And use that class for XML serialization.

Comment: Is `Bitmap` the standard framework `Bitmap`, or your own custom `Bitmap` class?

Comment: Bitmap is the standard framework Bitmap

Comment: What is the project type and .NET framework target version? What if you change the first line to `var corolla = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\corolla.jpg", true);`

Comment: `Bitmap is the standard framework Bitmap` I don't know how to say this nicely, but I am almost certain you are incorrect.

Comment: @AntonSizikov I can't believe it but that worked it wasn't using `System.Drawing.Bitmap;`. Thank you. What a mistake (face palm)

Comment: most probably you have a custom `Bitmap` class in your solution.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't spot this.

Comment: The giveaway was the 'show potential fixes'. See the namespace listed there. That isn't a standard namespace (Microsoft doesn't name them like that). That, plus the fact it was suggesting any code changes *at all* shows it must be related to your code (since it can't edit framework code).